# CSS2: how to achieve UL with 100% width, with flexible child LIs, each of which have a fixed-width margin in between?

Tags: html, css

Basically I'd like to know how to achieve this:

[image]

A `100%` UL with 5 x `20%` (floated) LI children, with `3px` gaps in between. The LIs have to be flexible (%) width so they can resize, but their gaps have to be fixed.

This can be done using CSS3 `width: calc(20%-3px)` but I need more basic CSS2 support. :(

What's the cleanest way to do this, please?

Comment: calc would be the cleanest way to do it, another way would be using javascript but its overkill imo, since most browsers support calc nowdays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is a bit of a work around, for it uses the container's background color as a border, but it works as expected (and with CSS2.1).

[image]

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/itay1989/JRz5E/3/)

```
.outer {
    background: lime;
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.inner {
    display: table-cell;
    background: green;
    width: 20%;
    height: 50px;
    border-left: solid 3px lime;
}
.inner:first-child {
    border-left: none;
}
```